# How to find a MKAnnotationView in MKMapView?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have a custom `PinAnnotation` and `PinAnnotationView`.  I have a carousel and the `selectedPinIndex` is the active card.  `PinAnnotation` has an `index: Int`

When `selectedPinIndex: Int` changes, I want to update the associated PinAnnotationView via a custom method `.select()`

```
func updateSelectedPin(_ mapView: MKMapView, selectedPinIndex: Int?) {
    if selectedPinIndex != nil {
        guard let annotations = mapView.annotations as? [PinAnnotation] else {
            return
        }
        
        
        // how do I find the associated PinAnnotationView for this annotation?
        // let annovationView = 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mapView` should has a method `view(for: MKAnnotation)` which should return the associated `MKAnnotationView`.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452512-view